# How to restrict access to nuget package?

Tags: nuget

I'm uploading a new package to NuGet but I would like to restrict the access to it for only a group of people using a user and password combination or something like that. I can not see a way to do this on the NuGet docs and haven't found something similar here on stackoverflow. Please help

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to use a nuget hosting service, such as https://www.myget.org/

Comment: Thanks for your answer. There is no way to do this using just nuget.org service?

Comment: No - that's why these hosted nuget services exist.